# How to show the actual data of [object Object] in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource, kendo-template

I'm trying to implement kendo grid with dynamic columns and the data showing [object Object].

How to show the address[object,Object] data in my kendo grid and i would like the sample output to be like the table below:-

```
Name       |  Phone         |     Address
------------------------------------------------
John Smith | (519) 420-2391 | Address 1: London
           |                | Address 2: 123
```

```js
 var peoples = [],
   address = [];


 peoples = [{
   id: 1,
   name: "John Smith",
   phone: "(519) 420-2391",
   address: [{
     address1: "london",
     address2: "123"
   }]

 }];

 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: {
     data: peoples,

   },
   scrollable: true,
   sortable: true,
   resizable: true,
   pageable: true,
   columnMenu: true,

   columns: [{
     field: "name",
     title: "Name"
   }, {
     field: "phone",
     title: "Phone number"
   }, {
     field: "address",
     title: "Address"
   }],

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `columns.template` functionality to achieve the desired result. ([Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template))

Depending on your data-structure you could use a template similar to this:

```
Address 1: <span>#: address[0].address1 # </span>
<br/>
Address 2: <span>#: address[0].address2 # </span>
```

I've also create a [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aYahE/2) showing an example.

Comment: If some of my data doesn't contain address 2 then the table will shown address 2:undefined. is there any way to remove or hide it?

Comment: You could send the addresses as an array. Then you could use a `for` loop within the template. Have a look at the [Template Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) to see what is possible.

Comment: Is this look fine to you? [my sample](http://jsbin.com/juzoxoquru/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: You just need to change the check whether `address2` is set from `&&` to `||`. As a value cannot be `null` and `undefined` at the same time.